# MySQL Query takes too long to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE tb_incident (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  what tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  when bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  where tinytext NOT NULL,
  where_longitude_latitude point NOT NULL,
  who tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  why tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  description text,
  created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY id_UNIQUE (id),
  KEY index_main_items (what,when),
  SPATIAL KEY location_index (where_longitude_latitude)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I try running this query,

```
SELECT db_incident.distance(point(132.6,15.604436765987833),where_longitude_latitude,'mi') AS "Distance in miles", 
X(where_longitude_latitude) AS "Longitude", 
Y(where_longitude_latitude) AS "Latitude" 
FROM db_incident.tb_incident 
WHERE db_incident.distance(point(132.6,15.604436765987833),where_longitude_latitude,'mi') <= 5
LIMIT 100
```

It takes over 10 minutes to execute, sometimes it gives this error **Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query**

My table has over 10 million records. Can someone please take a look and see if there is a way the query can be optimized.

**NOTE:** db_incident.distance is a function that returns the distance between two points.

Below is the **EXPLAIN** of the query.

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb_incident | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 11689629 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please take the time to correctly format your question in future.

Comment: Post the output from the `EXPLAIN` query.

Comment: Since the WHERE clause has to do a calculation, it can't use any indexes. It has to calculate the distance for every row in the table until it finds 100 that match the criteria.

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation on optimizing spatial queries. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimizing-spatial-analysis.html

Comment: You might want to generate a bounding box containing the radius to hit the spatial data with first so the index can be used.  From there you could use your distance function to cull the results down if you need a super precise radius only.

Comment: @sakkaku I wanted to use the Buffer function, but I don't know what unit of measurement the second parameter takes.

Comment: @DubemEnyekwe `These functions are not implemented in MySQL` on that page.  Look at `MBRContains` and `MBRWithin`, one of those should work while hitting the index.

Comment: @sakkaku I am trying to create an X mile buffer around a point. So I am using, the **Buffer** function to create my buffer, then I use the **MBRContains** to see if a given point is within that buffer. The problem now is that the  **Buffer**  function takes two arguments, the first one a geometry, and the second a distance. I dont know whether the distance is in **Miles** or **KiloMeter**